# How to remove the firsts n characters from a string in Elixir?

Tags: string, elixir

I have a list of strings. Each of those strings starts with n characters I want to get rid of.

I can't use something like `"123" <> new_string = old_string` because **the characters can be anything**.

So I'd like to do something like this:

```rb
my_list |> Enum.map(fn(str) ->
  # Remove the n leading characters from str
end)
```

Do you know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `String.slice/2` to remove the first N graphemes of a string, and `binary_part/3` or pattern matching to remove the first N bytes of a string.

Setup:

```
iex(1)> a = "abc"
"abc"
iex(2)> b = "πr²"
"πr²"
```

Removing the first 2 graphemes of a string:

```
iex(3)> String.slice(a, 2..-1)
"c"
iex(4)> String.slice(b, 2..-1)
"²"
```

Removing the first 2 bytes of a string:

```
iex(5)> binary_part(a, 2, byte_size(a) - 2)
"c"
iex(6)> binary_part(b, 2, byte_size(b) - 2)
"r²"
iex(7)> remove = 2
2
iex(8)> <<_::binary-size(remove), rest::binary>> = a; rest
"c"
iex(9)> <<_::binary-size(remove), rest::binary>> = b; rest
"r²"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```rb
defmodule StringExtensions do
  def remove_first_n_chars(s, n) do
    {_, new_string} = s |> String.codepoints() |> Enum.split(n)
    new_string |> Enum.join()
  end
end
```

Which would then be used like so:

```rb
l = ["abcdefg","hijklmno","pqrstuv"]

l2 = l |> Enum.map(fn str -> StringExtensions.remove_first_n_chars(str,2) end) # l2 -> ["cdefg", "jklmno", "rstuv"]
```

Just wanted to offer a potential alternative, FWIW.